# Download d3 charts on click in sapui5

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg, sapui5

I have created a venn diagram using d3 in Sapui5. 
Note: I have created circles inside  tag and inside  tag i have used  tag for styling the circle.

Now i have a Button when i click on the button the svg can be downloded and can be viewed. 
                           [image: SVG Image]

The styles are not shown.

I am doing like this onclick

```
    d3.select("#save").on("click", function(){
  var html = d3.select("svg")
        .attr("version", 1.1)
        .attr("xmlns", "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg")
        .node().parentNode.innerHTML;

  console.log(html);
  //var imgsrc = 'data:image/svg+xml;base64,'+ btoa(html);
  //var img = '<img src="'+imgsrc+'">'; 
  //d3.select("#svgdataurl").html(img);

});
```

could any one help me out to solve this problem.

Comment: It's not clear to me exactly what your question is. [ask]

Answer (score 1):

The styles are not shown because they are not included in your SVG document.
You can have a `<style>` tag in your SVG (see [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/style)).

For your specific case, I would specify the CSS rules for this diagram in a separate file which you can fetch (again) on save and include into the SVG before offering it for download.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing to do with sapui5. you can add style to svg something similar to this `.attr("fill", "red"); or .style("fill","red")` . There is much more to this have a look at [this](http://www.d3noob.org/2014/02/styles-in-d3js.html).